# Не изменяются размеры элементов в Design

Tags: android-studio

После создания первого проекта перестали изменяться размеры элементов в дизайнере. Создание нового проекта и полный сброс настроек Android Studio не помог. Можно только перемещать мышкой элементы на Activity, а изменять их размеры не получается, хотя в самом начале всё работало. Может-быть я что-то не правильно делаю и надо включить эту функцию в самой Android Studio? На прикреплённом скриншоте видно, что я увеличиваю размер мышкой, когда отпускаю размер размер не изменяется, остаётся прежним.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Никогда не пользуйтесь дизайнером, он баженый и не рабочий. Нужен исключительно для внешнего представления (картинкой) и набором виджетов (когда вручную будете писать в XML, в скором времени надобность во взятии с дизайнера отпадет).

Разрабатываю без него, исключительно во вкладке с XML, жить можно.

Comment: Ну, не рабочий - это преувеличение. Он работает, хотя и не без нюансов. Я делаю в дизайнере, но атрибуты выставляю через вкладку "свойства". Разумный компромис - и сразу видно результат и печатать меньше и "глюков" минимум.

Answer (score 0):

Устанавливать нужные размеры в Вашем XML-layout'е - единственный нормальный выход.